# Display data from database into listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have my database all set up and running. But now the problem I have run into is loading it into a listview. I've tried the other questions on the site but nothing answers my question. From a beginner(ish) perspective. What do I do to load the database into the listview?

This is what I have in my class: (the display class is at the bottom)

```
public class Inventory extends Activity {

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
private Cursor cursor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inventory_screen);


    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/databases/InventoryDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("InventoryDB"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    try {
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                DisplayRecord(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE:" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

// List View
public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c) {
    ListView InventoryItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewInventory);



    String[] Items = new String[] {c.getString(1)};

            ArrayAdapter<String> ItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Items);

            InventoryItems.setAdapter(ItemsAdapter);




    //Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Inventory.this, "id: " + c.getString(0)
        //  + "\n" + "Item: " + c.getString(1) + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //msg.show();
}
```

I just have a list view set up to pull the 1st item in the database (Thats all my knowledge extends to)

How would I have it display all the data? I've heard of the simpleCursorAdapter's but I have no idea if that is relevant?

Comment: Have you checked the Android guide on `Listview` that shows how to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: And if you want to do it the *right* way, use the Loader API (as explained in the above link).

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
public void display()
     {      
            ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);     

            String from[] = new String[] {db.KEY_DATE,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_ROWID};
            int  to[] = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text3,R.id.text5,R.id.text9};

            SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to)            
      {
            @Override
          public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
            {   

text1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DATE)));
                                text5.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_INCOME)));                         
                                text9.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_ROWID)));  

Set to the textview according to your requirement..


};

     lv.setAdapter(notes); 
     }
```